# Extracting dom elements from html using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to extract links to the articles including the text, from [this site](http://www.winbeta.org/) using [PHP Simple HTML DOM PARSER](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

[image]

I want to extract all `h2` tags for articles in the main page and I'm trying to do it this way:

```
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.winbeta.org');
    $articles = $html->getElementsByTagName('article');
    $a = null;

    foreach ($articles->find('h2') as $header) {
                $a[] = $header;
    }

    print_r($a);
```

according to the manual it should first get all the content inside `article` tags then for each article extract the h2 and save in array. but instead it gives me :

[image]

**EDIT**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems:

- `getElementsByTagName` apparently returns a single node, not an array, so it would not work if you have more than one *article* tag on the page. Instead use `find` which does return an array;
- But once you make that switch, you cannot use `find` on a result of `find`, so you should do that on each individual matched *article* tag, or better use a combined selector as argument to `find`;
- **Main issue:** You must retrieve the text content of the node explicitly with `->plaintext`, otherwise you get the object representation of the node, with all its attributes and internals;
- Some of the text contains HTML entities like `&#8217;`. These can be decoded with `html_entity_decode`.

So this code should work:

```
$a = array();
foreach ($html->find('article h2') as $h2) { // any h2 within article
    $a[] = html_entity_decode($h2->plaintext);
}
```

Using `array_map`, you could also do it like this:

```
$a = array_map(function ($h2) { return html_entity_decode($h2->plaintext); }, 
               $html->find('article h2'));
```

If you need to retrieve other tags within articles as well, to store their texts in different arrays, then you could do as follows:

```
$a = array();
$b = array();
foreach ($html->find('article') as $article) {
    foreach ($article->find('h2') as $h2) {
        $a[] = html_entity_decode($h2->plaintext);
    }
    foreach ($article->find('h3') as $h3) {
        $b[] = html_entity_decode($h3->plaintext);
    }
}
```

Comment: It definitely works but in the strings there is some encoded stuff, how do i deal with those? (snapshot in the edit)

Comment: `Microsoft back in China&#8217;s`

Comment: that should be `Microsoft back in China's`

Comment: And there is one more thing, what if I wanted to extract several elements from each article and save in different arrays, of course I could just run the same code again and replace the `h2` with different element but this way we would extract the articles several times and that's a waste. Is there a way to get all articles once and then operate on them?